# Not able to annotate the Kong ingress controller with AKS private load balancer

Tags: azure, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, kong, kong-ingress

I have a private AKS cluster and I am trying to configure the ingress for this AKS cluster. I am planning to use the Internal LB for Azure by annotating the the Kong Proxy service with
annotations:
service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: “true”

Need guidance how can I add the annotation during the install of Kong Ingress controller using helm by passing a parameter. I did try using below command but it did not work as I can see a public Azure LB in the cluster resource group

helm install kong/kong
–namespace ingress-kong
–generate-name --set ingressController.installCRDs=false
–set service.annotations.“service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal”=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure which service needs to be an internal load balancer, but according to the values there are several ways of adding annotations to different parts of the chart, you just need to use a proper one, like the one on line 79:

https://github.com/Kong/charts/blob/main/charts/kong/values.yaml#L79

```
--set admin.annotations.xxx.=true
```

Comment: thanks for the guidance. Here is the command that I used after reviewing all the options and tweaking them as needed while doing the helm deployment for KIC. 

helm install kong/kong \
--generate-name \
--set ingressController.enabled=true \
--set ingressController.installCRDs=false \
--set admin.type=LoadBalancer \
--set admin.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-load-balancer-internal"=true \
--set proxy.type=LoadBalancer \
--set proxy.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-load-balancer-internal"=true

Comment: @NeelabhKher my internal load balancer is being created but i can not access the external IP from outside the cluster , why is that?

Comment: start a new question with more details